# NotePad++ Changing Few Number Entries

Tags: programmers-notepad

Here is a simple lists where I like to change the numbers: the entries are as below and it got over 300 entries like it

```
tom112
smith113
harry114
linda115
cindy106
samantha147
```

It need to be changed to

```
tom212
smith213
harry214
```

...and so on.

Please assist using notepad++ regular expression.

Thanks.

Comment: What would you like to replace 'tom917' with? Or will it always be 'name1xx'

Comment: Is this even the right tag for Notepad++?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's just a matter of replacing a name followed by a number starting with 1 with the same number but starting with 2 instead:

- `Ctrl + H` for search & replace.
- Check `Regular expression` under `Search Mode`.
- Next to `Find what` type or copy in `([a-zA-Z]+)1([0-9]+)`.
- Next to `Replace with` type or copy in `\12\2`.
- Click `Replace All` and that should do it.

Add any other characters that might appear in the name before the number inside the first set of brackets with `a-zA-Z`.